# Correcting squat form, mild knee pain, numb thumb

Tags: workout, squats, stronglifts, knees

Basically started with the low bar squat (following [StrongLift 5*5](http://stronglifts.com/squat/)) but being very skinny (179 cm, 58 KG) the bar doesn't rest at the shelf created in scapula as described by Mark Rippetoe in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2tyOLvArw0). If I try going that low, the bone hurts there. This led me to squat with the bar a little up, somewhere on the traps, which qualifies for the high bar squat. Things went smoothly till now, when for the last couple of workouts I noticed a mild knee pain afterwards, its just some sensation that I know goes away with rest.

Secondly as the weight has got a bit heavier the current bar placement also feels on the bone, which I guess causes the thumb to go numb after the workout. Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuM6kyVqrOA&) I shot today to check my form.

Please advice me for these two issues and point out things that I can do to improve my squats and bear more weight.

Comment: The video is private.  Can you change the settings so we can see?

Comment: This is the best video I've found for squat form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoZWgTrZLd8

Comment: Things have changed now, had to stop working out altogether because of long job hours :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a high or low bar squat should necessarily cause knee pain: both are okay when performed correctly. As such, I wouldn't look at that as the cause of your issue. The low bar squat is "better" because you can push more weight. There are a lot of competitive level crossfitters that never low bar squat: their knees are fine.

Regardless of all of that, work your back with deadlifts, rows, and pullups. Stretch the front of your chest. When you build a bit of meat up on your back and can push your shoulders back the ridge will be there.

Even for people with decent back muscle, the low bar position can feel weird at first. After a while it becomes pretty comfortable, especially as the weight gets heavier.

Answer (score -1):

You can do Goblet Squats (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WrvQ2LEyGw) until your scapula is resistant enough.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (what can be improved in the original squat's form). It's very short too, which would have made it better as a comment.

Comment: Goblet squats are a thing that you can do to improve your squats, and I thought that's what's asked for. It's technically much easier than barbell squats and allows to focus more on technique.

Comment: Maybe we focused on different aspects of the question and you actually answered (half of) the question. It's still super short for an answer and better suited as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try Bulgarian split squats with just your bodyweight. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxFjYVinea4